# Creating a new column in a dataframe based on the result of the addition of three others

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have produced the following code:

```
data['Customer_segment'] = np.where(((data['Order frequency segment']+data['order_size_seg']+data['MOVC % segment'])<=5,1),
np.where((data['Order frequency segment']+data['order_size_seg']+data['MOVC % segment'])>5 & (data['Order frequency segment']+data['order_size_seg']+data['MOVC % segment'])<=8,2),
np.where((data['Order frequency segment']+data['order_size_seg']+data['MOVC % segment'])>8 & (data['Order frequency segment']+data['order_size_seg']+data['MOVC % segment'])<=11,3),
np.where((data['Order frequency segment']+data['order_size_seg']+data['MOVC % segment'])>11 & (data['Order frequency segment']+data['order_size_seg']+data['MOVC % segment'])<=14,4),5)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Would really appreciate help to reach the best solution, I feel like the one I'm trying to do may not be optimal.

example of input as follows:

```
MOVC % segment  order_size_seg  Order frequency segment
1                      2                 3
5                      2                 1
5                      5                 5
```

I am trying to add a column based on the result of summing each row as follows:

if 3-5 then 1
if 6-8 then 2
if 9-11 then 3
if 12-14 then 4
if 15+ then 5

Would really help with this

Comment: there is problem you miss `()` for each conditions - `() & () &()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need instead multiple `np.where` one [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
#only once sum values 
a = data['Order frequency segment']+data['order_size_seg']+data['MOVC % segment']
#conditions with ()
m1 = a<=5
m2 = (a>5) & (a<=8)
m3 = (a>8) & (a<=11)
m4 = (a>11) & (a<=14)

data['Customer_segment'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3, m4],[1,2,3,4], default=5)
```

Another solution is use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [-np.inf,5,8,11,14, np.inf]
labels = [1,2,3,4,5]

data['Customer_segment'] = pd.cut(df['B'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Comment: We think the same way :), Will delete my answer , and upvote for you ~

Answer (score 2):

How about try `pd.cut`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[5,2,1],[5,5,5]], columns=['M','O','F'])

pd.cut(df.T.sum(),[5, 8, 11, 14,np.inf],labels=[1,2,3,4]) 

Out[1180]: 
0    1
1    1
2    4
dtype: category
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the `query` method ? It seems to have really powerful syntax:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[5,2,1],[5,5,5]], columns=['M','O','F'])
d.query("5 < M+O+F < 8")

Out[4]: 
   M  O  F
1  5  2  1
```